# Create a new font family iOS

Tags: ios

I am using three fonts of same family but only one font is applied to my UI as other fonts are overridden when i am using pixate framework.

I thought to create  new families with one format and use.

How to create a new font family? Or is there any other alternate solution?

Comment: you may need to take a look on the `CoreText.framework`, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html, that holds advanced technology to work with fonts and texts.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up your project and define .otf font files in plist? If it so;

You can get all families like this;

```
NSArray *familyNames = [UIFont familyNames];
```

this array will give you font names and whener you want will use.

```
viewLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFont-500" size:18.0];
```

Comment: yes i have tried that but using that i will get only family names but i want to create a new family

Comment: yes i know i just want to be sure setup font correctly.